# Warning: Instance created by `useForm` is not connect to any Form element

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where built a form and i want to setDefaultValue for the form.
I used: `const [form] = Form.useForm();`. My form tag looks like bellow:

```
<Form form={form} name="basic" onFinish={onFinish} onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}>
```

And i try to set defaultValue:

```
form.setFieldsValue({
  name: object.name,
});
```

Here i get the next warning: `` Warning: Instance created by `useForm` is not connect to any Form element. Forget to pass `form` prop? ``

I saw many answers with this topic, but they solved the issue by adding `form={form}`. In my case it doesn't work. What could be the issue?

Comment: can you share full code or codesandbox?

Comment: @iamhuynq, code is like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-9t144

Comment: hmm, i see no warning here

Comment: @iamhuynq, when i use this in my application, not on sandbox, the warning appears

Comment: @iamhuynq, now te warning appear here: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-9t144

Comment: @iamhuynq, do the warnig appears now?

Comment: yes, i'm checking

Comment: in my case I checked if modal visible `if(!visible) return;` before `form.setFieldsValue`. It works.

Answer (score 34):

Before Modal opens, children elements do not exist in the view. You can set `forceRender` on Modal to pre-render its children. [source](https://ant.design/components/form/#Why-is-there-a-form-warning-when-used-in-Modal)

```
  <Modal forceRender visible={visible} onOk={okHandler} onCancel={closeHandler}>
    <Form form={form}>
      <Form.Item name="user">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  </Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
works for my case) with child form into modal

Comment: In my case, there was a Tabs component inside the modal also, so I used forceRender in the TabPane that the Form was located in.

Comment: Strange that on their example page they're not using `forceRender` in source code https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-form-in-modal and no warning dropped (maybe because of prod mode).

Answer (score 19):

If you are using `Form` component inside `Modal` component, pls remind set `getContainer={false}` to `Modal` component.

Here is the link: https://ant.design/components/modal/

Comment: After months looking for some way to fix this warning, finally I've solved! Thanks for this response, you helped me a lot

Comment: This applies to `Drawer` too. Thanks!

Comment: antd pro did not contain this `getContainer `

Answer (score 14):

I think it's warning because you call form method

```
form.setFieldsValue({
    note: text.note,
    gender: text.gender
});
```

before form instance patch on the form component `<Form form={form}...`. So I think you should call it when `componentDidMount`

```
useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({ note: "2", gender: "demo" });
    setText({ note: "2", gender: "demo" });
}, []);
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
    setText({ note: "2", gender: "demo" });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue({ note: text.note, gender: text.gender });
}, [text]);
```

Answer (score 8):

I fixed the problem by using `form.__INTERNAL__.name` as this will be undefined if the instance created by `useForm` is not connected to any form element (remember to set name property on your form element or `form.__INTERNAL__.name` will be undefined in both cases).

```
const form = useForm();
if (form.__INTERNAL__.name) {
   // do form logic here
   form.setFieldsValue({name: "Ahmed Hamed"});
}

...
<Form name="myForm" form={form}>...</Form>
...
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. I am using a method of `form` inside useEffect.

Comment: I think you should not use what is part of the internal implementation. At any time, the implementation may change and this code will stop working.

Answer (score 4):

## Update from 2023-11-24

The correct way would be to set the initial values via `useEffect`, as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61057608/8785369

## Original answer

The following helped me.

I deleted the code:

```js
const [form] = Form.useForm();
```

The assignment of initial values is done like this:

```js
<Form 
  name="basic"
  onFinish={onFinish}
  onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
  initialValues={{
    name: object.name,
  }}
>
```

Comment: And if form is used not only to set the initial data for the form?

Comment: @BuGaGa thanks for the comment! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
setTimeout(function () {
      form.setFieldsValue(node);
    },0);
```

This is how I solved it

Answer (score 3):

My case was because `Form` was conditionally rendered, like:

```js
// ...
useEffect(() => {
  form.setFieldsValue({ name: collectionName }) // this warns
}, [collectionName])

if (conditionalInitiallyTrue) {
  return <span>None</span>
}
return (
  <Form
    form={form}
    initialValues={...}
    onFinish={...}
  >
)
```

How did I solve it: using `ref`.

```js
// ...
const formRef = useRef(null) // set initial ref as null

useEffect(() => {
  if (formRef.current) // verify ref link with current
    form.setFieldsValue({ name: collectionName })
}, [collectionName, conditionalInitiallyTrue, form]) // run useEffect when formRef updates

if (conditionalInitiallyTrue) {
  return <span>None</span>
}
// set ref in Form (fomRef.current will update as soon this appears)
return (
  <Form
    form={form}
    initialValues={...}
    onFinish={...}
    ref={formRef}
  >
}
```

Not sure if this is helpful but, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to put values in form before open modal, you get this error. To avoid this you need populate form values after modal is rendered

Answer (score 2):

I also adopted this solution

```
setTimeout(function () {
  form.setFieldsValue(node);
},0);
```

not beutifull but this way solves, instead I wasn't able to intercept with useEffect. 
a bit of my current code

```
const EditModal = () => {
const [form] = Form.useForm();
const [visible,setVisible] = useState(false);

[...]

EditModal.open = (data) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.setFieldsValue({ title: data.title, des: data.des, });
    },0);  
    setVisible(true);
} 

return <>... <Form form={form}
```

Answer (score 2):

What eventually helped me was to put the modal inside the actual **Form** tag that is placed in the component. This way, I wouldn't depend on forceRender and strange behaviours related.

```
<Form form={form}>
    <Modal visible={isModalVisible}>
        <Form.Item label="something">
            <Input />
        </Form.Item>
    </Modal>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out this problem came when you call form instance before  component was rended, just check useEffect or something else was call form before component was render

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case `Form.useWatch` solved my issue when I was trying to access a field value using `form.getFieldValue` to pass the value to another Hook..

Example from the [docs](https://ant.design/components/form#formusewatch):

```
const Demo = () => {
const [form] = Form.useForm();
const userName = Form.useWatch('username', form);

const { data: options } = useSWR(`/api/user/${userName}`, fetcher);
return (
    <Form form={form}>
      <Form.Item name="username">
        <AutoComplete options={options} />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Works on version `> 4.20.0`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Form component in Modal and you want to `form.setFieldsValue(initialData)` with your initial data, do it in inside useEffect and add checking only call `form.setFieldsValue(initialData)` when modal `isOpen`

Example:

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const [form] = Form.useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  if (initialData) {
    if (isOpen) form.setFieldsValue(initialData);
  }
}, [form, initialData, isOpen]);

return (
<Modal isOpen={isOpen}>
  <Form form={form}>
   ...
  </Form>
</Modal>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The error is that when the page on which the modal window with the form is located is first rendered, it usually looks like `<Modal open={false}/>`, respectively, the form that is inside the modal window is not created. That's why the warning appears :

> Warning: Instance created by `useForm` is not connect to any Form element

To make sure of this, you just need `<Modal open={true}/>` and there will be no mistake

**Solving the problem:**

```
//ParentComponent.tsx

import {ModalWithForm} from './ModalWithForm';
import { Form } from "antd";
import { useState } from "react";

export const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {isModalOpen && <ModalWithForm setModal={setIsModalOpen} />}
      <Button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)} /> //show your component with Modal
    </>
  );
};


// ModalWithForm.tsx
import {  Form, Modal } from "antd";


export const ModalWithForm = ({ setModal }: any) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  return;
  <Modal
    open
    title="Show form"
    onOk={() => setModal(false)} //any of your code
    onCancel={() => setModal(false)}
  >
    <Form form={form} />
  </Modal>;
};
```

Thus, you will avoid situations when you use userForm() and at the same time, you do not have the  component itself

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to display one form first and after submitting the first form, display the second form, hiding the first (Depending on the condition). After displaying the second form I encountered the same problem. The solution turned out to be that you need to set the **key** property for the Form.

Full example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Input } from 'antd';
import { useForm } from 'antd/lib/form/Form';


const SomePage = () => {
    const [isForm1, setIsForm1] = useState(true);
    const [form1] = useForm();
    const [form2] = useForm();

    const onFinishForm1 = (values) => {
        console.log('Form 1 values:', values);
        setIsForm1(false);
    };

    const onFinishForm2 = (values) => {
        console.log('Form 2 values:', values);
        form2.setFields([
            {
                name: 'field2',
                errors: ['Some Error'],
            },
        ]);
    };
    if (isForm1) {
        return (
            <Form form={form1} onFinish={onFinishForm1} key={"form1"} >
                <Form.Item name="field1" label="Field 1">
                    <Input />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Submit Form 1
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <Form form={form2} onFinish={onFinishForm2} key={"form2"}>
                <Form.Item name="field2" label="Field 2">
                    <Input />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Submit Form 2
                    </Button>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        )
    }
};

export default SomePage;
```