# Instance created by `useForm` is not connected to any Form element. Forget to pass `form` prop with antd pro

Tags: typescript, ant-design-pro

Today when I add the Form fields reset code in antd pro:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  ProFormText,
  ProFormTextArea,
  ModalForm,
  ProFormSelect,
} from '@ant-design/pro-form';
import { useIntl, FormattedMessage, useModel } from 'umi';
import { getDictPair, getDictRenderText } from '@/utils/data/dictionary';
import { Form } from 'antd';

export type FormValueType = {
  company?: string;
  address?: string;
  city?: string;
  status?: number;
} & Partial<API.InterviewListItem>;

export type UpdateFormProps = {
  onCancel: (flag?: boolean, formVals?: FormValueType) => void;
  onSubmit: (values: FormValueType) => Promise<void>;
  updateModalVisible: boolean;
  values: Partial<API.InterviewListItem>;
};

const UpdateForm: React.FC<UpdateFormProps> = (props) => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const [form] = Form.useForm()
  const { initialState } = useModel('@@initialState');

  useEffect(() => {
    form.resetFields();
    form.setFieldsValue(props.values);
  });

  return (
    <ModalForm
    form = {form}
    title={intl.formatMessage({
      id: 'pages.apps.jobs.interview.updateInterview',
      defaultMessage: 'New rule',
    })}
    width="400px"
    visible={props.updateModalVisible}
    onVisibleChange={(value)=>{
      if(!value){
        props.onCancel();
      }
    }}
    onFinish={props.onSubmit}
    >
      <ProFormText
        initialValue={props.values.company}
        name="company"
        label={intl.formatMessage({
          id: 'pages.apps.jobs.interview.searchTable.company',
          defaultMessage: '',
        })}
        width="md"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: (
              <FormattedMessage
                id="pages.searchTable.updateForm.ruleName.nameRules"
                defaultMessage=""
              />
            ),
          },
        ]}
      />
    </ModalForm>
  );
};

export default UpdateForm;
```

the console shows warning info like this:

```
devScripts.js:6523 Warning: Instance created by `useForm` is not connected to any Form element. Forget to pass `form` prop?
```

I already read this question: [Warning: Instance created by `useForm` is not connect to any Form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056421/warning-instance-created-by-useform-is-not-connect-to-any-form-element) but I did not found the `getContainer` properties in antd pro. what should I do to fix this problem? Also tried the `forceRender` but still did not fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when Modal visible is flase, the child nodes are not rendered, and the form cannot find the corresponding Form at this time.
Therefore, you should perform form-related operations when visible is true.
For example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  ProFormText,
  ProFormTextArea,
  ModalForm,
  ProFormSelect,
} from '@ant-design/pro-form';
import { useIntl, FormattedMessage, useModel } from 'umi';
import { getDictPair, getDictRenderText } from '@/utils/data/dictionary';
import { Form } from 'antd';

export type FormValueType = {
  company?: string;
  address?: string;
  city?: string;
  status?: number;
} & Partial<API.InterviewListItem>;

export type UpdateFormProps = {
  onCancel: (flag?: boolean, formVals?: FormValueType) => void;
  onSubmit: (values: FormValueType) => Promise<void>;
  updateModalVisible: boolean;
  values: Partial<API.InterviewListItem>;
};

const UpdateForm: React.FC<UpdateFormProps> = (props) => {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const [form] = Form.useForm()
  const { initialState } = useModel('@@initialState');

  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.updateModalVisible) {
       form.resetFields();
       form.setFieldsValue(props.values);
    }
  });

  return (
    <ModalForm
    form = {form}
    title={intl.formatMessage({
      id: 'pages.apps.jobs.interview.updateInterview',
      defaultMessage: 'New rule',
    })}
    width="400px"
    visible={props.updateModalVisible}
    onVisibleChange={(value)=>{
      if(!value){
        props.onCancel();
      }
    }}
    onFinish={props.onSubmit}
    >
      <ProFormText
        initialValue={props.values.company}
        name="company"
        label={intl.formatMessage({
          id: 'pages.apps.jobs.interview.searchTable.company',
          defaultMessage: '',
        })}
        width="md"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: (
              <FormattedMessage
                id="pages.searchTable.updateForm.ruleName.nameRules"
                defaultMessage=""
              />
            ),
          },
        ]}
      />
    </ModalForm>
  );
};

export default UpdateForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Modal
...
forceRender={true}
/>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.